# Why Wifi is not working in this Asus laptop of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, ralink, ubuntu-drivers, asus

My Asus laptop wifi is listed as hard block on `rfkill` and *unblock all* does nothing.
I dual boot with Windows 10. The wifi works fine on Windows. I have tried a live USB of Fedora and the wifi cannot be turned on using it.
I have also tried setting the `wapf` value for `asus_nb_wmi` in the conf. These have failed. I have no physical button besides the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> key. 
These are some commands outputs for debugging:

```
$ rfkill list all
    0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
    1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
    2: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: yes


$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R CIe [105b:e055]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci


$ lsmod | grep asus
    asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
    asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
    wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
    video                  40960  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi


$ modinfo rt2800pci
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
    license:        GPL
    firmware:       rt2860.bin
    description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
    srcversion:     26CCED9E0CE5EFBFA9B8882
    ...
    depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

$ modinfo asus_nb_wmi
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/asus-nb-wmi.ko
    alias:          wmi:0B3CBB35-E3C2-45ED-91C2-4C5A6D195D1C
    license:        GPL
    description:    Asus Notebooks WMI Hotkey Driver
    author:         Corentin Chary <corentin.chary@gmail.com>
    srcversion:     3C571A40D6EF5CE0EC109E8
    depends:        asus-wmi
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           wapf:WAPF value (uint)


$ sudo lshw -class NETWORK
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0f0
       version: 00
       serial: 84:4b:f5:2b:18:99
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7910000-f791ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: enp4s0f2
       version: 0a
       serial: 74:d0:2b:1b:12:e4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 ip=192.168.254.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7810000-f7810fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

The lines below were taken from the script results here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 31 Aug 2016 10:56 PHT +0800

Booted last: 31 Aug 2016 00:00 PHT +0800

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Xubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0718:063d Imation Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp4s0f2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp4s0f2' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.254.2  Bcast:192.168.254.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f068:9aed:a42e:a84d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:64576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64820 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:90989807 (90.9 MB)  TX bytes:4956711 (4.9 MB)

wlp3s0f0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp3s0f0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0f2  no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.254.254 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0f2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp4s0f2
192.168.254.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0f2

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2397     1  0 10:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0f2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0f2' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.2/net/enp4s0f2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp4s0f2
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       7cf65578-7430-4080-896c-e9eab485c163
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   7cf65578-7430-4080-896c-e9eab485c163 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.254.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.254.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.254.254
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1472724292
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.254.254
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.254.2
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.254.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.254.254
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.254.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.254.254
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::f068:9aed:a42e:a84d/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::9261:cff:fe1e:c3d9
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::9261:cff:fe1e:c3d9/128, nh = ::, mt = 100

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0f0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-34-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0f0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0f0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Manila (based on set time zone)

country PH: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 17), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp4s0f2  no frequency information.

wlp3s0f0  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0f0  Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

enp4s0f2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     26CCED9E0CE5EFBFA9B8882
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2800mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2800 MMIO library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     01C1A7641505065E52E0388
depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     BB9F48B63A82C3FD3E73BAF
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211,crc-ccitt
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 pci library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     543B84557258F153AC267F0
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 mmio library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     ADBE279820CFD0A1081C682
depends:        rt2x00lib
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     72E39180D883A5541F66494
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800pci]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf]
options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Driver information from Windows:

```
Manufacturer:   Ralink Technology, Corp.
Description:    802.11n Wireless LAN Card
Driver version: 5.0.48.0
```

OS: Xubuntu 16.04
Hardware: Asus X450CC
Dual-boot: Windows 10

Comment: check that there isn't a setting in BIOS to disable the wireless hotkey (Fn+F2)

Comment: `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"` should fix it after reboot.

Comment: @Zanna, I have reset the BIOS to default settings and it has no disable for wifi.

Comment: @Pilot6, I have tried this fix and the wifi is still blocked.

Comment: @joriber What is the exact name of your laptop? It will help us to debug this. - - Please, be more specific when you say that you do `unblock all`. Please, say how you do it and why.