# Ubuntu 20.04 wi-fi not working

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an UX31A Notebook Asus laptop.

The Wi-fi worked the first 2 minutes then shut down. I can't relaunch it and get the error message: "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

I tried:

- Re-installing the Wi-Fi driver through the ubuntu iso. But there are no additional drivers to install
- Disabling secure boot mode
- A lot of random things found in various threads
- fn+F2 only enables/disables the airplane mode, it has no impact on the wi-fi
- Checked parameters in BIOS, wi-fi is not blocked

This is the output of a few diagnostic commands

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 24
       serial: c4:85:08:aa:c5:94
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-53-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 6000g2b-6.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep wlp
[4.565003] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.166969] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    4.242244] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 6000g2b-6.ucode op_mode iwldvm
[    4.242290] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    4.290348] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    4.290351] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    4.290352] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    4.290355] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
[    4.302808] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[    4.302832] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    4.323905] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    4.565003] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[  377.942252] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
```

```
$ lsmod | grep -e asus -e wmi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
asus_nb_wmi            32768  0
asus_wmi               36864  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd                    94208  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
asus_wireless          20480  0
wmi                    32768  1 asus_wmi
video                  49152  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

After I run `sudo modprobe -r asus-wireless`, fn+f2 no longer enables/disables airplane mode but it doesn't change the wi-fi status.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i -A2 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
$ sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

```
$ ethtool -i wlp2s0
driver: iwlwifi
version: 5.8.0-53-generic
firmware-version: 18.168.6.1 6000g2b-6.ucode
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

```
$ service network-manager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-30 12:33:51 CEST; 14min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 625 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 4516)
     Memory: 14.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─625 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

 NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9664] dhcp4 (enx9cebe80f5ca5): state changed unknown -> bound
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9722] device (enx9cebe80f5ca5): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9883] device (enx9cebe80f5ca5): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9887] device (enx9cebe80f5ca5): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9894] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9911] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9913] policy: set 'Connexion filaire 1' (enx9cebe80f5ca5) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371477.9923] device (enx9cebe80f5ca5): Activation: successful, device activated.
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371478.2308] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
NetworkManager[625]: <info>  [1622371487.3372] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=2255 uid=1000 result="success"
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux XXX-UX31A 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`hardinfo` Comupter -> Kernel Modules:

```
Kernel Modules
Loaded Modules
rfcomm  Bluetooth RFCOMM ver 1.11
cmac    CMAC keyed hash algorithm
algif_hash  
algif_skcipher  
af_alg  
bnep    Bluetooth BNEP ver 1.3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi  HDMI HD-audio codec
snd_hda_codec_realtek   Realtek HD-audio codec
snd_hda_codec_generic   Generic HD-audio codec parser
ledtrig_audio   LED trigger for audio mute control
nls_iso8859_1   
intel_rapl_msr  Driver for Intel RAPL (Running Average Power Limit) control via MSR interface
snd_hda_intel   Intel HDA driver
snd_intel_dspcfg    Intel DSP config driver
snd_hda_codec   HDA codec core
snd_hda_core    HD-audio bus
snd_hwdep   Hardware dependent layer
mei_hdcp    MEI HDCP
snd_pcm Midlevel PCM code for ALSA.
uvcvideo    USB Video Class driver
videobuf2_vmalloc   vmalloc memory handling routines for videobuf2
intel_rapl_common   Intel Runtime Average Power Limit (RAPL) common code
videobuf2_memops    common memory handling routines for videobuf2
snd_seq_midi    Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer MIDI synth.
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    X86 PKG TEMP Thermal Driver
snd_seq_midi_event  MIDI byte <-> sequencer event coder
videobuf2_v4l2  Driver helper framework for Video for Linux 2
intel_powerclamp    Package Level C-state Idle Injection for Intel CPUs
snd_rawmidi Midlevel RawMidi code for ALSA.
rtsx_usb_ms Realtek USB Memstick Card Host Driver
coretemp    Intel Core temperature monitor
videobuf2_common    Media buffer core framework
kvm_intel   
iwldvm  Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
memstick    Sony MemoryStick core driver
kvm 
videodev    Video4Linux2 core driver
snd_seq Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer.
mac80211    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
asix    ASIX AX8817X based USB 2.0 Ethernet Devices
btusb   Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.8
usbnet  USB network driver framework
btrtl   Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1
btbcm   Bluetooth support for Broadcom devices ver 0.1
mii MII hardware support library
crct10dif_pclmul    T10 DIF CRC calculation accelerated with PCLMULQDQ.
libarc4 
btintel Bluetooth support for Intel devices ver 0.1
snd_seq_device  ALSA sequencer device management
mc  Device node registration for media drivers
bluetooth   Bluetooth Core ver 2.22
ghash_clmulni_intel GHASH hash function, accelerated by PCLMULQDQ-NI
aesni_intel Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, Intel AES-NI instructions optimized
iwlwifi Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
ecdh_generic    ECDH generic algorithm
asus_nb_wmi Asus Notebooks WMI Hotkey Driver
ecc 
crypto_simd 
snd_timer   ALSA timer interface
asus_wmi    Asus Generic WMI Driver
joydev  Joystick device interfaces
cryptd  Software async crypto daemon
sparse_keymap   Generic support for sparse keymaps
glue_helper 
rapl    
i915    Intel Graphics
snd Advanced Linux Sound Architecture driver for soundcards.
intel_cstate    
input_leds  Input -> LEDs Bridge
cfg80211    wireless configuration support
efi_pstore  EFI variable backend for pstore
serio_raw   Raw serio driver
drm_kms_helper  DRM KMS helper
soundcore   Core sound module
cec Device node registration for cec drivers
rc_core 
i2c_algo_bit    I2C-Bus bit-banging algorithm
mei_me  Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
fb_sys_fops Generic file read (fb in system RAM)
syscopyarea Generic copyarea (sys-to-sys)
sysfillrect Generic fill rectangle (sys-to-sys)
sysimgblt   1-bit/8-bit to 1-32 bit color expansion (sys-to-sys)
mei Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
acpi_als    ACPI Ambient Light Sensor Driver
mac_hid 
kfifo_buf   
int3400_thermal INT3400 Thermal driver
acpi_thermal_rel    Intel acpi thermal rel misc dev driver
industrialio    Industrial I/O core
int3403_thermal ACPI INT3403 thermal driver
asus_wireless   Asus Wireless Radio Control Driver
int3402_thermal INT3402 Thermal driver
int340x_thermal_zone    Intel INT340x common thermal zone handler
sch_fq_codel    Fair Queue CoDel discipline
parport_pc  PC-style parallel port driver
ppdev   
lp  
parport 
drm DRM shared core routines
ip_tables   IPv4 packet filter
x_tables    {ip,ip6,arp,eb}_tables backend module
autofs4 
rtsx_usb_sdmmc  Realtek USB SD/MMC Card Host Driver
rtsx_usb    Realtek USB Card Reader Driver
xhci_pci    xHCI PCI Host Controller Driver
psmouse PS/2 mouse driver
lpc_ich LPC interface for Intel ICH
xhci_pci_renesas    
ahci    AHCI SATA low-level driver
libahci Common AHCI SATA low-level routines
i2c_i801    I801 SMBus driver
crc32_pclmul    
i2c_smbus   SMBus protocol extensions support
wmi ACPI-WMI Mapping Driver
video   ACPI Video Driver
```

Network -> Intergaces -> wlp2s0:

```
Network Adapter properties
Interface Type   Wireless
Hardware Adress (MAC) : XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (hidden)
MTU 1500

Transfer Details:
Bytes received 0 (0.00 MIB)
Bytes transferred 0 (0.00 MIB)
```

Devices -> PCIDevices -> Network:

```
PCI Devices
Host bridge Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
VGA compatible controller   Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Signal processing controller    Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
USB controller  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Communication controller    Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
USB controller  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Audio device    Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
ISA bridge  Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
SATA controller Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
SMBus   Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
Signal processing controller    Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
Network controller  Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

```
$ ls -al /etc/modprobe.d
total 56
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 févr.  9 19:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 129 root root 12288 juin   3 21:51 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2507 juil. 31  2015 alsa-base.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   154 févr. 16  2020 amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   325 mars  12  2020 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1518 mars  12  2020 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   210 mars  12  2020 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   677 mars  12  2020 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   156 juil. 31  2015 blacklist-modem.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    41 juin   2 22:59 blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   583 mars  12  2020 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   154 nov.  12  2020 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   347 mars  12  2020 iwlwifi.conf
```

```
$cat /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf

cat: /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf: No such file or directory
```

```
$cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

```
$cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-53-generic root=UUID=a3725b5e-92ec-415b-87c6-e8d2a326cc17 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

```
$modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-56.ucode
srcversion:     F1C209D24ECAFDEE75AF058
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*
[bunch of aliases]
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        35:38:57:EC:63:07:C2:02:DE:90:95:7A:ED:63:B0:27:D4:D0:8A:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      63:F9:F1:24:1D:2E:5B:61:21:0D:34:0C:02:E5:29:91:94:71:B7:60:
        77:5C:44:DF:D9:07:4E:F2:0A:BC:3D:45:3C:E0:CC:EC:02:2B:24:44:
        37:93:15:04:75:DE:25:3E:99:06:33:1A:F4:21:61:7D:57:6B:A1:A5:
        67:E9:2A:79:7B:C3:EA:8E:AC:26:E9:F8:2A:A0:61:73:1C:00:5D:AF:
        B9:97:76:FB:DC:77:6F:98:F7:A4:E4:EA:CB:04:3A:30:B6:7A:B4:09:
        AF:A7:F4:A1:BE:FA:76:1C:66:30:99:EB:D8:82:8A:86:D6:79:07:93:
        BF:B1:24:D3:6C:E3:26:FA:C1:48:8C:43:04:56:3E:6D:3B:19:BD:B2:
        82:65:D5:E2:A0:BC:3D:F9:8C:1C:2C:D5:D1:00:CD:04:E8:28:98:75:
        F5:9C:EE:58:93:9F:59:90:60:77:AF:AE:3F:02:0B:19:5A:CE:4C:72:
        E7:BE:D7:0A:20:04:2A:CD:26:3F:1A:5A:16:BC:ED:DA:B6:6C:40:AC:
        5B:97:22:46:07:09:04:82:22:8C:DD:27:8A:B4:19:F6:2D:1A:ED:CA:
        F2:6A:1C:B8:5D:14:DB:D9:F0:30:75:D8:CC:3D:70:CA:21:53:1A:E6:
        7B:5A:C3:AB:D6:0D:EB:C5:EA:E5:C7:AB:A4:C4:81:A2:DB:47:0A:15:
        20:91:0C:36:36:05:DB:93:54:32:6D:6C:F3:B7:88:F9:12:DB:76:62:
        1E:B9:3F:1B:4F:47:14:28:28:80:15:83:72:67:DC:82:0B:9E:09:3E:
        A6:78:2C:DD:BE:85:75:8A:9A:06:3E:09:B2:7C:67:E6:73:AD:9D:83:
        C7:49:3B:84:53:E4:40:E5:B8:6B:89:56:27:97:AF:35:43:70:12:6F:
        B9:5E:DF:D3:18:6C:29:F6:3D:6C:4C:F3:6D:52:D6:51:65:8F:FD:30:
        C8:AF:43:C2:33:35:94:F4:64:CA:5C:80:05:09:AA:46:D8:67:AC:7F:
        CC:5A:F9:1C:CF:78:C1:A0:16:46:F4:63:1E:72:B8:81:A2:0C:51:F7:
        E3:6E:C2:5E:F6:A3:18:61:21:5B:4F:56:39:0C:BA:30:4C:C3:CF:2A:
        E7:4F:1D:48:0F:5B:6D:62:B7:2F:11:6A:DC:63:E0:18:E8:39:FB:99:
        5F:3E:3C:FB:11:FE:CE:4C:52:F0:D8:8C:80:A7:B6:C0:0C:2C:F0:0F:
        8B:7F:CC:F5:B5:DD:4C:D4:8C:00:23:56:D1:93:03:CE:F1:E8:22:89:
        08:3F:E1:00:C4:B5:6F:9C:5D:30:6D:C0:B3:65:48:62:EA:86:03:AF:
        91:F7:EA:30:77:4E:A5:B5:D5:50:F3:68
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

```
$ ls -al &(locate rfkill |grep service)
[1] 45522
total 80
drwxr-xr-x 15 francois francois 4096 juin   3 21:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 juin   2 23:03 ..
-rw-------  1 francois francois  605 juin   4 22:03 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 francois francois  220 juin   2 23:03 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 francois francois 3771 juin   2 23:03 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Bureau
drwx------ 13 francois francois 4096 juin   3 21:58 .cache
drwx------ 11 francois francois 4096 juin   3 21:58 .config
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Documents
drwx------  3 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 .gnupg
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Images
drwxr-xr-x  3 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 .local
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Modèles
drwx------  5 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Musique
-rw-r--r--  1 francois francois  357 juin   3 21:53 .pam_environment
-rw-r--r--  1 francois francois  807 juin   2 23:03 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Public
-rw-r--r--  1 francois francois    0 juin   3 21:58 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Téléchargements
drwxr-xr-x  2 francois francois 4096 juin   2 23:10 Vidéos
/snap/core18/1988/lib/systemd/system/systemd-rfkill.service
/snap/core18/2066/lib/systemd/system/systemd-rfkill.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-rfkill.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-rfkill.service
/usr/share/man/man8/systemd-rfkill.service.8.gz
[1]+  Done                    ls --color=auto -al
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to enable the network ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks you for the welcome ! I added the results. You are on to something, the wireless lan is hard blocked. I tried different keyboard shortcuts (fn+f2) and looking in the BIOS, unfortunately without any success

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop?

Comment: It is an UX31A Notebook Asus PC

Comment: Are you saying that Fn+F2 doesn't change: `rfkill list all`? May we see: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: I added the result of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`. The Fn+F2 only changes the Soft Lock of the Wi-Fi, not the Hard block.

Comment: May we see: `lsmod | grep -e asus -e wmi`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I just added it to the question !

Comment: The usual helper module *asus-wireless* is loaded but not, as you see, working correctly. Please try unloading it and tell us if there is any improvement: `sudo modprobe -r asus-wireless` Now does Fn+F2 remove the hard block?

Comment: I can feel we are close to solving it. Unfortunately the command does not remove the Hard Block. Removing the asus-wireless module only stops fn+f2 from enabling/disabling the airplane mode. But it doesn't enable/disable the hard lock..

Comment: My aging memory just clicked! Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/questions/744774/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-15-10/744849#744849 wapf=1

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried wapf=1 and =4, none worked. Both keep assigning fn+f2 to the airplane switch.. I also updated the firmware without any success

Comment: I regret that I have no further suggestions. Sorry. I recommend that you file a bug report against asus-wireless: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: Thank you for your help, I put a bounty on the question and will report the bug if no answer is found. If there is no answer by the end of the bounty time, feel free to write an answer with all the tips you gave me, I'll give you the reputation ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Diagnosis

Please post the output of

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i -A2 net
$ ip a
$ sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up
$ ethtool -i wlp2s0
$ service network-manager status
$ uname -a
$ ls -al /etc/modprobe.d
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
$ cat /proc/cmdline
$ modinfo iwlwifi
$ ls -al $(locate rfkill | grep service)
```

**EDIT**

```
$ dmesg | grep phy0
```

Plus, you can install `hardinfo` and inspect *Computer* -> *Kernel Modules*, *Devices* -> *PCI Devices*, *Network* -> *Interfaces* -> *wlp2s0*.

I wouldn't think this relates to the kernel version, as some reported in old posts.

### Possible solutions

Try:

1. Disabling Secure Boot/Fast Boot in BIOS ([source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=266219)) and Fast Startup in Win 10 if possible ([source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1986287#p1986287)).
2. `sudo rfkill unblock all` ([source](https://comeandtechit.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill/)).

**EDIT**

3. [This](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1615691&sid=489d012e605e85d0dc5e2c24a96f56b4#p1615691) and [this](http://rfkillhandler) show options to be placed in a suitable `/etc/modprobe.d/` file, maybe `rfkill.conf`.
   I am not sure which apply to `iwlwifi`.
   I would try adding

   ```
   options rfkill master_switch_mode=1
   options rfkill default_state=0
   ```

   to file `/etc/modprobe.d/rfkill.conf` and rebooting.
4. [This post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill-4175677291/#post6137323) in an old thread for slackware shows a solution to a somewhat similar problem.
   You might try checking the whole thread and find possible analogies with your current Ubuntu.
   Posting whatever partial conclusions also helps.
5. [This post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1356981#p1356981) and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1324810#p1324810) in old threads for archlinux show a solution to another somewhat similar problem, blacklisting some driver.
   A similar solution for archlinux is shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/578827/226614) for a soft blocking.
   So you might try

   ```
    echo "blacklist asus_wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_wmi.conf
   ```

   (used e.g. [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2322831.html), one of the threads where chilli555 took part) and further like [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-blacklist-a-module-on-ubuntu-debian-linux) for full blacklisting dependencies.
   I am not certain `asus_wmi` is the right module to blacklist.
   Reboot and run

   ```
    sudo rfkill unblock all
   ```

I guess you might try finding the proper config file where to remove the driver, unblock, and then reload the driver.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002113/226614) seems to do that, but at the command line and for a soft blocking, not the same as your case.

I will wait until you post feedback.

### Related

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875921 ?
2. [I have to issue "rfkill unblock wifi" at every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673950/i-have-to-issue-rfkill-unblock-wifi-at-every-boot)
3. https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=11918.0
4. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-rfkill.service.8.html
5. [Why Wifi is not working in this Asus laptop of Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813903/why-wifi-is-not-working-in-this-asus-laptop-of-ubuntu-16-04)
6. [WiFi not showing on Ubuntu 16.04 - Asus ROG GL502VMK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948286/wifi-not-showing-on-ubuntu-16-04-asus-rog-gl502vmk)
7. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=275294
8. [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)
9. [How to unblock something listed in rfkill?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill/578827#578827)

Comment: I added all the info you requested in the question ! I tried disabling fast boot in the bios without any success

Comment: @vlemaistre Are you dual booting with Windows?

Comment: I am not dual booting with Windows. I removed Windows when I installed Ubuntu 20.04. The `sudo rfkill unblock all` unfortunately doesn't remove the hard block

Comment: The command doesn't output anything

Comment: Can you detail which commands you're talking abour ?

Comment: I added them except the last one. The locate package has some trouble installing. I'll post it if I'm able to install it

Comment: I tried again and installed the package, I added the last command. Yes the package is mlocate, I had an error 'waiting for cache lock'

Comment: @vlemaistre - 
1) After which command you got `waiting for cache lock`?
2) Is that the complete message you received? Most other sources suggest it is not.
3) Please post in the question (not scattered in comments) each exact command you use, followed by the exact and complete output you get. This minimizes guess-work, and maximizes chances of arriving at a solution (your extra attention to detail potentially pays off well).
4) If you really used `ls -al &(locate rfkill |grep service)` as posted, note that it should be `ls -al $(...`.

Comment: 1) After trying to install mlocate aka `sudo apt install mlocate` 2) No there was indeed more text. I did not include this message since I was able to install the package later on. I no longer have the corresponding terminal. 3) As said in 2) I don't think this part is necessary and think it will just add noise to the question (feel free to correct me if you think this part is vital) 4) I updated the answer, it seems I might have put the wrong input mb

Comment: @vlemaistre - 
Please see EDIT, and post feedback, and full output of what you get. Just check in other forums how that helped solving problems.

Comment: @vlemaistre - I posted additional info. Sometimes the solution is not straightforward (or the person who could provide it does not "show up"), so it requires some interaction. I guess this is one such case, and your chances of solving the problem rely now on your taking the time to try and post feedback.

Comment: Definitely not a straightforward problem (at least for now). Thanks for all your suggestions @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio. I just tested your solutions 3-5 without any success. Additionally I looked at many of the links you provided and tried everything I found adapting it to my use case (reboot iwlwifi module, reset bios settings, etc..) but this hard switch does not want to change state.. I'll try to install another distribution of Ubuntu this afternoon